# Referee.cpp:10:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘Human::Human()’ Referee::Referee()

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm new to c++ and was having problem with doing some inheritance, does any one know why im getting this error? (its the only error I'm getting when compiling).

I compiled with g++ -o. Also I'm so sorry in advance if I'm doing a lot of things wrong here, I'm very new to c++. >_<
Please let me know how I can make my code better or more efficient.

**computer.h**

```
#ifndef RPS_H
#define RPS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


class Computer 
{
    public: 
    Computer(std::string);
    ~Computer();
    char charc;
};

#endif
```

**human.h**

```
#ifndef HUMAN_H
#define HUMAN_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


class Human 
{
    public: 
    Human(std::string);
    ~Human();
    char charh;

};

#endif
```

**referee.h**

```
#ifndef REFEREE_H
#define REFEREE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "human.h"



class Referee : public Human{
    public: 
    Referee();
    ~Referee();
    bool Winneris();
};

#endif
```

**Computer.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "computer.h"

using namespace std;

Computer::Computer(string char_c)
{
}
Computer::~Computer()
{
}
```

**Human.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "human.h"

using namespace std;

Human::Human(string char_h){
char_h=charh;
cout<<"r/p/s?"<<endl;
cin>>charh;
}

Human::~Human()
{
}
```

**Referee.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "referee.h"

using namespace std;

Referee::Referee(){
}

bool Referee::Winneris(){

if (charh=='r'){
    cout<<"draw"<<endl;
}
else if(charh=='p'){
    cout<<"Victory!"<<endl;
}
else if(charh=='s')
{
    cout<<"Defeat"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}

Referee::~ReReferee(){
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "human.h"
#include "computer.h"
#include "referee.h"


using namespace std;
string char_h;
string char_c;
// main program
int main()
{

    Human *round1h;

    round1h = new Human(char_h);

    Computer *round1c;

    round1c = new Computer(char_c);

    Referee *round1r;

    round1r = new Referee();

    round1r -> Winneris();
}
```

Comment: Remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationship. `Referee` *is a* `Human`. Now think about the `Referee` initialization... When you create a `Referee` object you also create a `Human` object. And unless you explicitly invoke a `Human` constructor in the `Referee` *constructor initializer list* the `Human` part of the object will be default constructed. The problem is that `Human` doesn't have a default constructor (a constructor that doesn't take any arguments).

Comment: You don't need all of this code to duplicate your error.  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11b4a0fd5919bc96).  Basically all compiler errors can be duplicated using minimal code you see at the link.

Comment: Tangentially, I notice that all of your class variables are *public*, but you ought to make them *private* (all the methods are OK, though). Part of the reason we encapsulate information into classes is to protect that information from other portions of code that have no business accessing it directly, but when you make everything public you lose this safeguard.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added a default constructor for then to realize that I might had got the question wrong, went about solving it the complete wrong way! The question is to make a Rock, Paper, Scissor game when the Computer always plays Rock. 
I wanted the Referee to take the Human's input and compare it with Rock and see if the Human wins or losses. Then I realized that inheritance doesn't help me solve that problem at all. lol

Comment: Also yes I have to get in the habit of using Private and Protected. Just really new to all of this. Thanks for the advice tho :).

Answer (score 0):

When you have written the parameterized constructor in respective classes. You have created the class objects, which call the default constructor which takes no parameter.

You have to define the default constructor as well in your respective classes.

```
Human::Human()
{}
Computer::Computer()
{}
Referee::Referee()
{}
```

[Constructor types](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/)